# How to get the old value of a reactive data source in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-tracker

I am looking for a way to get old value of a reactive data source in Meteor. Say I have this code:

```
const foo = new ReactiveVar(1);

Tracker.autorun(() => {
  const fooNewVal = foo.get();

  if (/* compare based on fooNewVal value */) {
    // do something
  }
});

foo.set(2);
foo.set(3);
foo.set(4);
```

What I want is somehow to get the old value of `foo`, use this old value with the new value to decide execution of if statement, like:

```
const foo = new ReactiveVar(1);

Tracker.autorun(() => {
  const fooNewVal = foo.get();
  const fooOldVal = foo.getOld();

  if (fooNewVal - fooOldVal === 1) {
    // do something
  }

  if (fooNewVal - fooOldVal === 2) {
    // do something
  }

});

foo.set(2);
foo.set(3);
```

I know I could use a normal variable to store the old value at the end of the `autorun` function:

```
const foo = new ReactiveVar(1);
let oldValue = 1;

Tracker.autorun(() => {
  const fooNewVal = foo.get();

  if (fooNewVal - oldValue === 1) {
    // do something
  }

  if (fooNewVal - oldValue === 2) {
    // do something
  }

  oldValue = fooNewVal;
});

foo.set(2);
foo.set(3);
```

Although it works, it does not look "right" for me. I searched Atmosphere and Npm but could not find a solution. Do you know any solutions or packages/modules to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is fine. It's a common practice to store a previous version of a variable. If you were fetching from the database, the data at the beginning of the autorun function will still be the old value. Autorun is triggered when the reactive variable changes, so in your case foo has already changed on entry.

Comment: I know I could do that, in fact I have been doing that all the time. But it does not feel "right" for me, does not look "pretty" at all. I prefer a more intuitive way, like `foo.getOld()`. I am ok with not having this `.getOld` for collection (have never needed it in fact), but for `ReactiveVar`, `ReactiveDict` it really bothers me to use a cache variables. Anyway thanks for your answer :)